# algebra generated by infinite collection of subsets

Tags: measure-theory

If I define algebra $\mathcal{F}(A)$ generated by $A$, collection of subsets of $S$ (the universal set) as the intersection of $\mathcal{F}$, algebra superset of $A$: $$\mathcal{F}(A)=\bigcap_{algebra\ \mathcal{F} \supseteq A}\mathcal{F}$$
What if $A$ is an infinite (either countable or uncountable) set? Algebra, unlike $\sigma$-algebra, guarantees being closed under *finite* Boolean operations. Here, finite(in the definition of algebra) and infinite(in the setting) confuses me. *e.g.* $A$ is the collection of intervals $(-\infty,x]$($x\in\mathbb{R}$) and $S=\mathbb{R}$, what $\mathcal{F}(A)$ be like?
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: E.g. the minimal $\sigma$-algebra that contains $A$ will also contain $(-\infty,0)  =\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty  (-\infty, \frac1n]$ while this is not the case for the minimal algebra that contains $A$.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma should it be intersection or union? well  I get the difference between $\sigma$-algebra and algebra here, from countable and finite, but I cannot figure out the idea between infinite and finite in my question. Briefly, say $(-\infty,0]\cup(-\infty,1]\cup(-\infty,2]$, now it's finite, what about continuing the process? Since $A$ is infinite, I can always  find another interval to do Boolean operations.

Comment: That union is just $(-\infty,2]$ and already in $A$; nothing new; Allowing infinite unions would add $\Bbb R$ as a compulsary member of the generated family. Algebras contain that set anyway. And they are closed under both unions and intersections.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma makes sense! I should go with mathematics but not trapped in finite and countable in a twisted way.

Answer (score 0):

You're intersecting **algebras** (that contain $A$) not subsets. Mind your types..

Comment: not sure what $\mathcal{F}$ is like :( cannot imagine not only superset of A but under countable operations.

Comment: @user567445 this definition serves the prove the *existence* of a minimal algebra or $\sigma$-algebra etc that contains $A$ but not a practical way to find that algebra.